# I can't update an object property inside the callback of readFile() in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I have the next object in Node.js:

```
function myObject(){
    this.allowed = false;
    this.rawData;
}

myObject.prototype.checkAccess = function(){

    var self = this;

    if (!this.allowed){
        fs.readFile("./file.key", function(err, data){
            if (err) return;
            self.rawData = data;
            self.allowed = true;
        })
        return;
    }

    // several operations with rawData
    // not intended to be called when file.key is read
    // but next time checkAccess is called, by example
    console.log(this.rawData);

    // or, by example, use its content to decrypt 
    // another file or data from a socket...
    var isCorrectlyDecrypted = this.decrypt(this.rawData);
    if (!isCorrectlyDecrypted) this.allowed = false;
}
```

I periodically call checkAccess with setInterval but what I found is that, existing file.key, I never have the rawData property updated, being always undefined, while allowed property updates sucessfully.

Can someone, please, explain what's happening and tell me what I'm doing wrong and what's the best way of doing it?

EDITED:

So, as I said, in the code that uses this class I have:

```
var myObjectInstance = new myObject();

setInterval(function(){

    // here some previous code

    myObjectInstance.checkAccess();

   // and here more code
}, 25)
```

What `checkAccess()` does is to look periodically for a `file.key` to read if present, and then wait until the next call to work with its content. SO, `console.log()` is not intended to be used right after `file.key` is readed, BUT the next times `checkAccess()` is called and subsecuently. That's why `console.log()` is not placed inside the callback.

Comment: When do you check the values of `rawData` and `allowed`?

Answer (score 4):

That's asynchronous programming. `console.log(this.rawData)` is called before the `fs.readFile` process is through (as it's a callback-function), giving you no output. Put the `console.log()` inside the `fs.readFile`-block and you'll see the output you want.

Have a look at the [async library](https://github.com/caolan/async). If you need a response after the process is finished, use an async-series or async-waterfall.

Comment: Actually he returns right after `fs.readFile(...)`.  So it would only log the `rawData` on a subsequent call to `checkAccess` if `allowed==true`

Comment: Even if it's self/this? Interesting.

Comment: Sure, a function is a function.  His workflow is a bit odd though.  That said, I still think you're right and it's an async issue.

Comment: As climbage said, first time I `checkAccess`, `console.log()` does not execute because it's not `allowed`, instead, an attempt to read file.key is done. The existence of that file determines `console.log()` gets executed next timeout. If I `console.log()` right after `self.rawData = data` I can see the Buffer printed on console...